# SQL server IF EXISTS vs IF Condition Perfomance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table `Business` (contains more than 10,000 rows) with a bit column `ISBILLINGBUSINESS`.
In a Stored procedure I have to check whether `ISBILLINGBUSINESS` is  True of False for a record.

I can compare with two methods.

(1)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM BUSINESS WHERE ID = 5404 AND ISBILLINGBUSINESS = 1)
select 'Billing Business'
```

(2)

```
IF((SELECT ISBILLINGBUSINESS FROM BUSINESS WHERE ID = 5404) = 1)
select 'Billing Business'
```

I want to know the performance wise difference for the following two methods. 
Which one is better? Can anyone help?

Comment: Check the query plans (CTRL-L). If they are the same then there is no difference. If you want performance in a database think more about indexes and ensuring your code is SARGable. However in a 10K row table, none of this matters as indexes won't be used. An an index alone on a bit column won't be used either.

Answer (score 0):

maybe effective code

```
 declare @Boolbillbuss bit
select @Boolbillbuss = ISBILLINGBUSINESS FROM BUSINESS WHERE ID = 5404
IF( @Boolbillbuss=1)
 select 'Billing Business'
```

Answer (score 0):

10K rows is usually too small for performance concerns. In any case, performance-wise it is important to have appropriate index(es), the form of the `IF` expression is not that important here.

If there is a unique index on `ID`, both variants are good and pretty much the same.

If `ID` is unique and is primary key with clustered index, then you have everything you need.

If the clustered index is different, or there is no clustered index on this table, create a covering index, which includes all columns that are referenced in the query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ID] ON [Business]
(
    [ID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([ISBILLINGBUSINESS])
```